# Copying a range of values to a complete separate Spreadsheet File

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a range of values into another Google Spreadsheet file but the current methods  on App Script doesn't allow copying across different files. Would appreciate the assistance, I'll attach the code I'm working with.

```
function mreport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //select current sheet
  var currentsheet = ss.getSheets()[1] ;

  //select current range
  var currentrange = currentsheet.getRange(46,1,1,14);


  //select destination spreadsheet
  var destspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Destination File");
 
  //select the sheet to put the completion data in
  var destsheet = destspreadsheet.getSheets()[2];

  //select destination range 
  var destrange = destsheet.getRange(27,2,9,14);

  //if one of the cell in the row is not empty, skip to the next row.
  if (destsheet.row === '')return;

  currentrange.copyValuesToRange(destsheet, 27,2,9,14).if (destrange.row === '').return;
}
```

I was expecting to copy specifically the values within the source range into the destination Spreadsheet File & range, whilst introducing the 'if' condition to skip a particular row if there are any value present in a cell.

The error was in the final line of code, where is says 'Target sheet and source range must be on the same spreadsheet'.

Comment: I think that the reason for your current issue of `The error was in the final line of code, where is says 'Target sheet and source range must be on the same spreadsheet'.` is due to that you are trying to copy the values from Spreadsheet "A" to Spreadsheet "B" using `copyValuesToRange`. In this case, `getValues` and `setValues` are useful. But, I cannot understand your expected situation from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your question.

Comment: Hiya, thank you for responding to my questions swiftly. I'm thinking to work around it by incorporating the 2 Spreadsheet file into 1 so that the function works. It seems that SpreadsheetApp methods are truly not applicable over distinct files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected situation from `I'm thinking to work around it by incorporating the 2 Spreadsheet file into 1 so that the function works.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Copy the entire sheet then copy the range from the copied sheet to the destination sheet then delete the copied sheet